# Second counting query for pagination

Tags: php, symfony

I have a couple of pretty complex queries, and for each of them I have to write a second query counting results. So for example, in the model:

```
$dql = "SELECT u FROM AcmeBundle:Users u LEFT JOIN AcmeBundle:Products p WITH u.id = p.id";
```

I would have to create a duplicate query like this:

```
$countingQuery = "SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM AcmeBundle:Users u LEFT JOIN AcmeBundle:Products p WITH u.id = p.id";
```

The main problem with that is that with every change in the first query, I would have to change the second either.

So I came up with another idea:

```
$countingSelect = "SELECT COUNT(u.id)";

$noncountingSelect = "SELECT u";

$dql = " FROM AcmeBundle:Users u LEFT JOIN AcmeBundle:Products p WITH u.id = p.id";

return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($noncountingSelect . $dql)
->setHint('knp_paginator.count', $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($countingSelect . $dql)->getSingleScalarResult());
```

It works of course, but the solution seems quite ugly with larger selects.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator will do what you're looking for, without the additional complexity.

```
$paginator = new Paginator($dql);
$paginator
    ->getQuery()
    ->setFirstResult($pageSize * ($currentPage - 1)) // set the offset
    ->setMaxResults($pageSize); // set the limit

$totalItems = count($paginator);
$pagesCount = ceil($totalItems / $paginator->getMaxResults());
```

Code yanked from: http://showmethecode.es/php/doctrine2/doctrine2-paginator/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a customer repository as explained in [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) and add your query to that with a minor edit like..

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findProducts()
    {
        return $this->findProductsOrCountProducts();
    }

    public function findCountProducts()
    {
        return $this->findProductsOrCountProducts(true);
    }

    private function findProductsOrCountProducts($count = false)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

        if ($count) {
            $queryBuilder->select('COUNT(u.id)');
        }

        $query = $queryBuilder
            ->leftJoin('AcmeBundle:Products', 'p', 'WITH', 'u.id = p.id')
            ->getQuery()
        ;

        if ($count) {
            return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
        } else {
            return $query->getResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call your method using...

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Users');

// for products
$products = $repository->findProducts();
// for count
$countProducts = $repository->findCountProducts();
```

**Note:**

I know it's not best practice to just say look at the docs for the customer repository bit s here' the YAML mapping...

```
# src/Acme/StoreBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Product.orm.yml
Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\ProductRepository
    # ...
```